# Program running, but not displaying anything?

Tags: java

I'm just getting back into Java programming and long story short, I made an Applet without knowing those can only run in browsers so I tried to change to code so I could put it in a runnable .Jar, but when I run my code it doesn't do anything.

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    setBackground(Color.black); //Sets the background to black.
    Font myFont = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 14); //Makes "myFont" a font that is plain.
    setFont(myFont); //Sets the font to "myFont"..
}

private static void setFont(Font myFont) {


}

private static void setBackground(Color black) {

}

public void paint(java.awt.Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.blue); //Sets anything in "paint" to be in blue.
    int xArray[] = {20, 110, 200, 200, 110, 20, 20}; //This line, and the line below are the cords for the bowtie.
    int yArray[] = {20, 45, 20, 100, 65, 100, 20};
    g.drawPolygon(xArray, yArray, 7); //Draws the bowtie.
    g.drawString("Bow ties are no longer cool.", 20, 150); //Writes the text.
```

}
}

Comment: You have a method setBackground() that does nothing, and a method setFont() that does nothing. I think it is not displaying anything because you never told the computer to do anything. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is only doing what you tell it to:

- The main method will run of course.
- It then calls setFont, setBackground, both methods of which do nothing since you've written them to do nothing
- And then the main method and the program ends.
- A `paint(...)` method will have no effect if it is not overriding the paint method of a Swing component, which yours is not.
- Better to override the paintComponent method of a Swing component, which the tutorials will tell you all about.

I'm surprised that you're expecting it to do more. If you want a GUI to actually show, then get most of your code out of the static realm and into the class or instance realm, have your code extend JPanel, override its paintComponent, and put your JPanel in a JFrame in your main method. Most important, read the tutorials as they will show you the best path for this. You can find links to the Swing tutorials and other Swing resources here: [Swing Info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swing)

For example,

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SwingExample extends JPanel {
   private static final int PREF_W = 400;
   private static final int PREF_H = 300;

   public SwingExample() {
      setBackground(Color.black); //Sets the background to black.
      Font myFont = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 14); //Makes "myFont" a font that is plain.
      setFont(myFont); //Sets the font to "myFont"..
   }

   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      g.setColor(Color.blue); //Sets anything in "paint" to be in blue.
      int xArray[] = {20, 110, 200, 200, 110, 20, 20}; //This line, and the line below are the cords for the bowtie.
      int yArray[] = {20, 45, 20, 100, 65, 100, 20};
      g.drawPolygon(xArray, yArray, 7); //Draws the bowtie.
      g.drawString("Bow ties are no longer cool.", 20, 150); //Writes the text.
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
         return super.getPreferredSize();
      }
      return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      SwingExample mainPanel = new SwingExample();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("SwingExample");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```